# How to prevent crypto while allowing string idx, etc in CnR

Tags: discussion, cops-and-robbers

In my [new sandboxed challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13379/58826), I'm looking to ban crypto / one-way functions that make it impossible to get the input from the output.

I started out requiring only using functions that are [bijectve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), but that bans functions that "gets a character from a particular index of a string", as [pointed out by aschepler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13379#comment47687_13379).

I would like to ban crypto / one-way functions that make the challenge not fun, while allowing functions that get a char from an index in a string, etc. How can I do this? **I'd prefer something that's worked in the past.**

Comment: You can just have a rule to explicitly ban "hashing, encryption, or random number generation." That's worked in the past.

Comment: I think that `a[b]` is pretty much one-way (e.g. `'The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog'[10]` would return `'f'` and there's no way to figure out where did the `'f'` come from).

Comment: Requiring bijective functions wouldn't prevent one-way functions anyway.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think that bijective functions always have an inverse, since every value maps to only one value, and is mapped to by only one value too.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer, existence is not the point. Computability is the point: it's easy to compute in the forward direction, but hard in the inverse direction.